# AVPlayerDemo Advancing to next frame for first time when the current time is zero .

Tags: avplayer, ios5.1, seek

I am using AVPlayerDemo open source code for play back of chosen video. 
The reason why I am using AVPlayerDemo is seeking of each frame is easy compared to MPMoviePlayerController.

In the AVPlayerDemo sample code , I have added a button "Next" where the click on "Next" will make the video to advance  to the next frame.

I have got a problem on advancing to the next frame , when the user is at the first frame of the video

When the video's  nominalFrameRate is 30 ,  from the above logic to seek to next frame , the log is mentioned below, on click of "Next" button does not advance the video.

Comment: Once the user manually scrubs to the second (or any later) frame there is no problem. 


current time {2002/30000 = 0.067} , 
one frame time  {1001/30000 = 0.033, rounded} 
added time {3003/30000 = 0.100, rounded}


the video will be seeked to the next frame with out any issues. 


When frame rate is 24 , video is not seeked to the next frame.  , from the above the log is mentioned below


current time {0/1 = 0.000}
one frame time  {0/1 = 0.000, rounded}
added time {0/1 = 0.000, rounded}


Am I missing some thing here ?

Comment: Advancing is calculated as below , 

CMTime currentTime = [mPlayerItem currentTime];
NSLog(@"********************** current time ******************** ");
    CMTimeShow(currentTime);
    CMTime oneFrame = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0 / mFrameRate, currentTime.timescale);
    NSLog(@"********************** one frame  ************* ******* ");
CMTimeShow(oneFrame);
CMTime added = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, oneFrame);
NSLog(@"********************** added  ******************** ");
CMTimeShow(added);
[mPlayer seekToTime:added toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];